# Push unique objects into array in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push object that only have unique `id1` into array.

`Example:`

```
let array = [],
    obj = {},
    access = true

if(access){
   obj['id1'] = 1
   obj['id2'] = 2
   if(array.indexOf(obj.id1) == -1){
       array.push(obj)
   }
}

console.log(array);
```

In the above example I am trying to add value to `obj` then push the `obj` into `array`. But `obj.id1` need to be unique. The method I am using above doesn't work in my case.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the `find` method for arrays.  The issue is that you are trying to match by a nested property, not the actual element in the array

Comment: Yes @Taplar that's the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As Taplar says, `indexOf` will look for the first instance of the thing you pass in in the other array. This won't work because there are no instances of the ids in the array, directly anyway.

Use the `find` function, which allow you pass in a comparison function, so you can define what a match is.

```js
let initial = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:1}];
let result = initial.reduce((acc, item) => 
{
  if(!acc.find(other => item.id == other.id))
  {
    acc.push(item);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution . Lets say myObjArray have duplicate object use below es6 code to get unique array from that

// Creates an array of objects with unique "name" property values.

> let uniqueObjArray = [
> ...new Map(myObjArray.map((item) => [item["name"], item])).values(), ];   console.log("uniqueObjArray", uniqueObjArray);

Refer here for more detail https://yagisanatode.com/2021/07/03/get-a-unique-list-of-objects-in-an-array-of-object-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `findIndex` and not `indexOf`.
Try replacing your `if` condition with the following:

```js
    array.findIndex((o)=>{ return o.id1  === obj.id1 }) === -1
```